# How do I share something to a list?

Tags: share-menu, notes, to-do-list

I frequently make lists of things, e.g. in Google Notes. I'm looking for a way to share anything (with a share button) to become a new item on a list. The app doesn't matter, as long as it lets me in turn share the whole list. Is this possible?

Comment: So not the default Keep Notes share option that is there - you want to add to a list instead of making a new note? Not sure how convenient that is because you'd need to select a list to add to etc would be faster to copy and paste.

Comment: Any text file shared to ColorNote becomes a new item.